# knockout simple binding not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding, jsfiddle

I am trying a simple example for binding an objects' attribute to a UI.

My example is here http://jsfiddle.net/arendu/m14mohda/17/

I have the following HTML:

```
The name is <span data-bind="text: personName"></span>
<button type="button" onlick="changeName()">Click Me!</button>
```

And the following js script:

```
var myViewModel = {
    personName: ko.observable('Foo'),
    personAge: ko.observable(123)
};

var changeName = function () {
    myViewModel.personName("Bar")
}
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

My question is why does the displayed name not change from 'Foo' to 'Bar' when the button is clicked?

Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle says `ko` is not defined.

Comment: I looked at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/lkqtu/ .. does not seem to have ko defined I am sure I am missing something, how do I define ko in fiddle?

Comment: The problem with the fiddle seems to be that you linked to the source using http when jsfiddle is in https by default.

Comment: Wow! Three roughly equivalent correct answers within 15 minutes.

Comment: @CrimsonChris thank you. I have a quick follow up : Should the changeName function be part of myViewModel? I understand that myViewModel.personName acts as a Getter/Setter, but should the function  triggering it be part of the ViewModel?

Comment: I can't say exactly what your code *should* do without more context. Think about what object should own the functionality and put it there. The way you had it before wouldn't work however, the default context on the button is `myViewModel`, so it's looking for the function there. @Tomalak's suggestion of using classes to keep your code cleaner is spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems with your code. The primary issue was in the way you were trying to set an observable. Observables should be used as getter/setter functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/m14mohda/16/

```
The name is <span data-bind="text: personName"></span>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: changeName">Click Me!</button>

var myViewModel = {
    personName: ko.observable('Foo'),
    personAge: ko.observable(123)
};

myViewModel.changeName = function() {
    var newName = myViewModel.personName() === 'Foo' ? 'Bar' : 'Foo';
    myViewModel.personName(newName);
}
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

This `myViewModel.personName = 'Bar'` is not going to work, since `personName` is an observable. When we want to get the observable's value, we simple call it as a function

```
 myViewModel.personName()
```

While, when we want to set it's value, we call it like above but passing the value as a parameter.

```
 myViewModel.personName("Bar")
```

You can think it as a getter and a setter.

```js
var myViewModel = {
    personName: ko.observable('Foo'),
    personAge: ko.observable(123)
};

myViewModel.changeName = function () {
    myViewModel.personName('Bar'); 
}
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
The name is <span data-bind="text: personName"></span>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: changeName">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I changed the fiddle based on what you said it still does not work : http://jsfiddle.net/arendu/m14mohda/15/

Comment: Please see my updated post. I altered a bit also you html code. I attached the click handler to your view model.

Answer (score 1):

First: You *never* use inline event handlers with knockout. Period. Everything is done through bindings.

Second: You *should* use classes as viewmodels, it will make your life easier.

```js
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name),
    this.age = ko.observable(age)
}
Person.prototype.changeName = function () {
    this.name('Bar');
};

ko.applyBindings( new Person('Foo', 123) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

The name is <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
<button data-bind="click: changeName">Click Me!</button>
```